# Instead of developing a dll , is there any another method or new technology in C# VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any new technology or methods that can be used / developed as a replacement for of dlls or ocx in c# / VS?

That is instead of developing a dll , is there any another method?

Comment: Very unclear what your goal is. Possibly COM interop / native interop may be an answer, but you really need to clarify specific problem rather than "replacement of DLL" which is way too broad.

Comment: Could you explain your endgoal? what do you want to achieve; and why dont you want to use a .dll?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, if your problem was solved by a dll in the past, most likely you want or need a dll using C# as well.

There are countless other ways to solve problems than a simple dll, but there has never been a 1:1 replacement. If you ask a question about your actual problem, people might suggest other options, but without this information, no, there is no simple one-size-fits-all replacement.